# Showing Latest Version VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I need to find a way to show latest version next to corresponding letter. I have two sheets. Sheet1 shows **ALL** the versions that been released so far (the list is constantly growing)
 i.e.:

[image]

and sheet2 where the list of available names are, and next to it I would like to have corresponding **LATEST** version only, so for example above this would be like follows

[image]

I was thinking to declare variable and use `.Find` method

```
Set SearchRange = Worksheets("VIEW").Range("A").End(xlDown)
Set FindLatestVersion = SearchRange.Find(What:=Version, MatchCase:=False, LookAt:=xlPart)
```

and use if statement.

Could anyone point me into right direction please?

Comment: https://excelchamps.com/blog/max-if-formula/ should do the trick with just normal excel formula

Comment: A dictionary would be a natural data structure for a VBA solution.

Comment: One easy approach would be to create a Pivot table (assuming all versions are a numeric value) and then set the value field setting as "MAX". If you convert your input list to a table then refreshing pivot is what it would take! You will not need any VBA with this route.

Comment: As @Luuklag said.  Or if you have the correct Excel version you could use [MAXIFS](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MAXIFS-function-dfd611e6-da2c-488a-919b-9b6376b28883) which isn't an array formula.

Comment: Unfortunately don't have MAXIFS. I did however used  {MAX(IF} did work like a charm, thanks for advise everybody